# Check why record is returned twice in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an `inward_doc_tracking_hdr` table with a total of **79** records.

But when I run the same thing in a stored procedure, I get a total of **80** records.

I checked the count and saw that one record count is 2.

[image: FF]

I want to know why the record is being returned twice.

Here is the query:

```
Select  
    UserName, Document_Type, 
    count(Doc_No) docno,
    Doc_No, No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending, UserEmail,
    RA1_Email  -- User table  
from 
    MainTempTable
group by 
    UserName, Document_Type, Doc_No, No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending, 
    UserEmail, RA1_Email, Doc_No
```

**UPDATE**

Also my below query returns 2 records.

```
Select   
             U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name UserName,   
             TH.To_User,   
             TY.Type_desc Document_Type,   
             RA.mkey Reporting_To,   
             U.Email AS UserEmail,   
             RAU.Email AS RA1_Email,   
             RAU.first_name + ' ' + RAU.last_name RAName,   
             TH.Doc_No,   
             DATEDIFF(DAY,TH.LastAction_DateTime,GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(WK,TH.LastAction_DateTime, GETDATE())   
                AS No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending  
            --INTO MainTempTable  
                from inward_doc_tracking_hdr TH   
                    inner join    
             user_mst U ON TH.To_User = U.mkey   
                inner join   
             emp_mst M ON M.mkey = U.employee_mkey   
                inner join   
            type_mst_a TY ON TY.master_mkey = TH.doc_type   
                inner join   
            emp_mst RA ON RA.mkey = M.Reporting_To   
                inner join    
                    user_mst RAU ON RAU.employee_mkey = RA.mkey   
            where   
                TH.Status_flag NOT IN (5,14) --- 5 for close, 14 for return   
                    and TH.To_user IS NOT NULL
                    and TH.To_User = 1019
```

Comment: Because you have used Group By for that specific column, remove group by for the column and check you get all rows.

Comment: If you intended to use `GROUP BY`, can you elaborate on what you were trying to do?

Comment: @Manjuboyz: I removed group by and still getting 80 records.

Comment: Remove the Count(),  it will give the number of counts not the rows. and what is the column name ? is it 'docno' ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I want to check the count why it was getting 80 records, since I have only 79 records

Comment: @Manjuboyz: I removed the count, now getting 79 records. Any special thing why it was earlier showing 80 records then ?

Comment: Count() will get the counts, thats why it was showing 2 in the specific column. if removing count works for you then no harm in using it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
Select  
UserName, Document_Type, 
 docno,
Doc_No, No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending, UserEmail,
RA1_Email  -- User table  
 from 
MainTempTable
 group by 
UserName, Document_Type,  No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending, 
UserEmail, RA1_Email, Doc_No
```

hope this helps you

[Count()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Comment: yes, Now m getting 79 records. But y it was giving me 80 records then ?? Any special reason

Comment: Now you won't see '2' there, you have to use Count() only  when : returns the number of rows that matches a specified criteria.

Comment: If you want number of values to specific column, like If I want to find number of things purchased under my name, then we should use Group By which will allow me to see the number of items with info.

Comment: ohh ok, Got it bro. Thanks a lot for the kind info

Comment: hi, kindly find the updated question. As i dont want to use group by

Comment: it resulted to different question now and let us know what result you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117783/discussion-between-n-k-and-manjuboyz).